# Acessing form from directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my custom directive I'm declaring new form `<div ng-form="inputForm"></div>` with input in it.
How can I access to this form within link function? `scope.inputForm` is `undefined`:/

Edit: code sample

```js
.directive('ifInput', ['$system', function ($system) {
 return {
  restrict: "E",
  replace: true,
  scope: {},
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   scope.temp = function () {
    console.log(scope.inputForm);
   }
  },
  templateUrl: "template/if-input-pola/index.html"
 };
}])
.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
 $templateCache.put("template/if-input-pola/index.html",
  "<div ng-form=\"inputForm\" class=\"form-group ng-fadeInLeft\" ng-class=\"{'has-error': inputForm[kolumna.id].$invalid && inputForm.$dirty}\">" +
   "{{inputForm|json}}"+ //here is correct object (with $error and so on)
  "<a ng-click=\"temp()\">a</a>" + //here is undefined

  "</div>"
 );
}])
```

EDIT 2:
Problem was that I wan's using object like this `ng-form="model.inputForm"` - now everything is ok

Comment: Can you post your directive definition object?

Comment: I've added code sample with comment

Comment: How are you using the `if-input` directive? You probably need to add to the definition something like `scope: { inputForm: '=ifInput' },`

Answer (score 0):

You can just define ng-model e.g. 
`<input ng-model="myInput">` and

```
link: function (scope, element) {
  console.log(scope.myInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm), using `ng-form="inputForm"` should post the controller on the local scope. If you cannot see it, you're either looking at a nested scope with that property overwritten, or at an ancestor scope. Keep in mind, that some directives, such as `ng-repeat` or `ng-if`, create local scopes, so in the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-if="someCondition">
        <div ng-form="myInput">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`myInput` would *NOT* be visible on the scope managed by `myController`.

---

When accesing the scope property within a `link` function, it also depends where your linked directive is, as the property may not be assigned to the scope yet. Try `$watch`ing the property and you just might find out it's being assigned later.

Comment: You're using isolated scope (`scope: {}`) in your directive definition, which makes your inner scope disconnected from the outer scope. [See documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: I use isolated scope, but link is ctrl from directive and ng-form is in directve.

Comment: The code you've pasted [works just fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JodQbP?editors=101). And if you put logging directly in the `link()` function, `inputForm` is visible as well.

Comment: I had to use object in `ng-form="model.inputForm"` - thanks for help